# WIN32 API freeing unlocked memory block

Tags: c, winapi

```
const HGLOBAL hGlobal = GlobalAlloc(GHND | GMEM_SHARE, sizeInBytes);
if(!hGlobal)
{
    error_set_last(ERR_MEMALLOC);
    CLOSE_CLIPBOARD
    return ERR_MEMALLOC;
}
LPVOID memoryBlock = GlobalLock(hGlobal);
if(!memoryBlock)
{
    GlobalFree(hGlobal);
}
```

Should I free hGlobal here if the GlobalLock function fails? Can an unlocked block of memory be freed?

Comment: If `GlobalAlloc()` succeeds, you need to free the block when you are done using it (unless you pass ownership of it to something else). So yes, if `GlobalLock()` fails (why do you think it will?), you still need to free the block.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I was confused when I saw this in the GlobalFree documentation: "The GlobalFree function will free a locked memory object". https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-globalfree

Comment: All that doc is saying is that if `GlobalLock()` succeeds and you don't call `GlobalUnlock()`, `GlobalFree()` will still free the block, so be careful (it will issue a debugger breakpoint before freeing the block). You should always unlock memory you have locked.

Comment: If you still worry about that, you can use `GlobalMemoryStatusEx` to retrieves information about the system's current usage of memory.

Comment: These functions teleported from the 16-bit version of the winapi, today they operate very differently.  GlobalLock() can never fail.  Use the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/using-the-clipboard) for guidance.  It is a bit inconsistent about it, but generally doesn't check if GlobalLock failed.  That's just fine.

Answer (score 1):

As [Remy Lebeau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/65863/remy-lebeau) said,

If `GlobalAlloc()` succeeds, you need to free the block. So Even if `GlobalLock()` fails, you still need `GlobalFree()` to free the block.